# Unable to get push token. Getting error: 907135004, EXECUTE_TIMEOUT

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I was able to get the token for push couple hours ago. After I reinstalled the application, I couldn't get the push token anymore and was getting error EXECUTE_TIMEOUT. According to HMS documentation, it suggested me to contact customer service. I'm unable to get registration token multiple times and don't know what is causing this to happen. My application code for getting the push token never changed, it worked before but not now.

Here is the log:

```
2021-05-10 15:37:45.969 29250-30669/com.myapp.push I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResult:0
2021-05-10 15:37:45.973 29250-29250/com.myapp.push I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
2021-05-10 15:37:45.975 29250-29250/com.myapp.push I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code907135004, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:100000000|, pkg_name:com.myapp.push, session_id:*, transaction_id:100000000ttoken20210510153735889477123, resolution:null
2021-05-10 15:37:45.976 29250-29250/com.myapp.push E/HMSSDK_HmsInstanceIdEx: TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 907135004
2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135004: execute timeout
2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.a.a(ErrorEnum.java:272)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.i.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:58)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.i.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:34)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.TaskApiCall.onResponse(TaskApiCall.java:190)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager$1.onCallback(HuaweiApiManager.java:272)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$a.a(HmsClient.java:100)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$a.onComplete(HmsClient.java:122)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.a(BaseAdapter.java:277)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:252)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:175)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$a.b(PendingResultImpl.java:490)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$a.handleMessage(PendingResultImpl.java:467)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8387)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)


2021-05-10 15:37:45.975 29250-29250/com.myapp.push I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code907135004, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:100000000|, pkg_name:com.myapp.push, session_id:*, transaction_id:100000000ttoken20210510153735889477123, resolution:null 2021-05-10 15:37:45.976 29250-29250/com.myapp.push E/HMSSDK_HmsInstanceIdEx: TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 907135004 2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135004: execute timeout 2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.a.a(ErrorEnum.java:272) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.i.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:58) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.i.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:34) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.TaskApiCall.onResponse(TaskApiCall.java:190) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.978 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager$1.onCallback(HuaweiApiManager.java:272) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$a.a(HmsClient.java:100) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$a.onComplete(HmsClient.java:122) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.a(BaseAdapter.java:277) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:252) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:175) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$a.b(PendingResultImpl.java:490) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$a.handleMessage(PendingResultImpl.java:467) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8387) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 2021-05-10 15:37:45.979 29250-30477/com.myapp.push W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error code suggests that [AIDL has a call timed out](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/code-0000001050185248-V1). Please try the steps as below:

1. Check whether your phone has internet access, verify that the network connection is stable and the notification function is enabled on the device.
2. Clear the app cache, HMS Core (APK) cache and restart the device.
3. Please verify that the token on the device is correct. You can send a message to the device from the console of AppGallery Connect. If the message was sent from the console but you still cannot receive it on the phone, the token has expired or the device configuration is incorrect. Please check the token and configure device permissions. If the message is successfully sent and received, we can conclude that the API parameters are set incorrectly.
4. Please check the format of the message body encapsulated on the server. You are advised to check the message body fields by referring to [Sending Downlink Messages](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5).

Comment: I just restart device and ıt's weird but ıt works, thanks.